# how do I solve build error on c# workflow project

Tags: c#, xaml, msbuild

I run nightly builds of a product consisting of over a thousand c# projects both in configuration Debug and Release.
For a few weeks now, without any code changes, I've been having problems with some workflow projects that use XAML.
For example:

> "C:\NETSIU\backend\netasiu\workflows4\workflows4.integrazione.fatturapassiva\workflows4.integrazione.fatturapassiva.csproj"
> (Build target) (689) -> (XamlMarkupCompilePass1 target) ->
> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Xaml.targets(193,5):
> error XC1000: XC1020: Build error occurred in the XAML MSBuild task:
> 'Could not load file or assembly
> 'file:///C:\NETSIU\Infra\Tipi.Workflow\bin\NETA.SUITE.Tipi.Workflow.dll'
> or one of its dependencies. Access is denied.'
> [C:\NETSIU\backend\netasiu\workflows4\workflows4.integrazione.fatturapassiva\workflows4.integrazione.fatturapassiva.csproj]

The error is not systematic. I solve the problem by compiling the single project again.

The nightly build is runned with the highest privileges.

Any suggestions to solve the problem?

Further information.
If I launch the full build by connecting to the machine, no errors are detected.
If I launch the full build on a scheduled basis, even if with maximum privileges, I have the error reported above.
The build is done on a Windows 2019 server and for the build I use the following build version:

set path = C: \ Program Files (x86) \ MSBuild \ 14.0 \ Bin;% path%

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.